# Direct Query Power BI - Cannot load visuals with big data

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We have direct query dashboard set up to connect to Azure database. Our Azure database has 15M rows for Fact table and on P2 tier.

From desktop version, it takes around 10 minutes to show visuals on dashboard, no error.

But when I tried to publish to Power BI Service or import to Power BI Embedded, most of visuals cannot be loaded.

[image]

And the detail of error is:
[image]

I am not sure what problem is, I guessed initially it's related to timeout, but I cannot find any configuration to setup timeout for Power BI Service.

And for Power BI Embedded, I also cannot find any property to set up timeout when updating the data source gateway using C# code.

Comment: This is likely a timeout - What is the expected amount of data that is being retrieved for the visuals?  I'd recommend optimizing your database to return your results faster.

Comment: @WallaceBreza: Thanks, is there any way that we can control this timeout, I try increasing to P4 tier and it works perfectly. But P4 is expensive for us

Comment: No, this timeout is not configurable in the service.

Comment: @WallaceBreza: Thanks, we can control the timeout on Power BI Embedded?

Comment: No, unfortunately the timeout is not configurable in Power BI Embedded either.

Comment: @WallaceBreza: thanks for your support, please answer as your mention, then I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a timeout - What is the expected amount of data that is being retrieved for the visuals? I'd recommend optimizing your database to return your results faster.

Unfortunately the timeout is not configurable in Power BI service or Power BI Embedded.